# Video Texture: Augmented Reality Framework for Android

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, textures, augmented-reality

Which frameworks have this feature? [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCoRVcMNj_E&feature=channel_video_title) I would like to implement something for Android. Are there already approaches? QCAR (Qualcomm AR SDK) has this feature not yet, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the QCAR SDK 1.5 Beta for Android only allows you to use the camera video as a texture. This differs from the posted video which shows a movie texture being loaded on a geometrical plane.

The Metaio Mobile SDK 3.0 does allow you to set movie textures on a geometry that matches the video.

http://docs.metaio.com/bin/view/Main/AdvancedContentExample#Movie_textures

Answer (score 0):

The QCAR SDK 1.5 Beta for Android now provides a simple and streamlined way of accessing the video background texture. Developers can now write custom special effects using powerful shaders resulting in far more exciting application experiences. :)

**Edit:** Now Vuforia has the [Video Playback sample](https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk). Devices from API-Level 14 (Android 4.0) support video on texture. Other devices will play the video in full screen mode.